# How to write the content of a web page to a local file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write to replicate the code and test cases from a Leetcode page into a local file

Basically to bypass the rate limit of compiling on leetcode, I would like to sync the code between my local file and the leetcode environment.

I would like

1. to copy the code from the leetcode text editor and prefix with some headers, main() and write to a local file (vscode workspace ex: C:/workspace/solution.cpp)
2. to copy test cases to a local testcases files (ex: C:/workspace/test.txt)

What I have tried: creating a chrome extension:
this can read from local file to browser, but cant write to a specific local filesystem
(i looked into [chrome extension storage api](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/storage) but its sandboxed?)

Comment: Why do you need the web page at all?  You can run all the test cases you want on your local machine, by running `Solution().problemName(...)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts  Right now to run a cpp program locally for leetcode, I have to 1.copy the Solution class, add a main(), add headers 2. copy test cases , append number of testcases at the beginning . I would like to automate this flow everytime I want to run  a program locally

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/web-apis/file-system-access